# Why do we even need profile when we have permission sets?

Tags: profile, permission-sets

A profile also provides permissions that defines how a user can access records whereas a permission set is also the same. I know a profile is more like a global feature but even a permission set can have many users. what is the key use of using a profile over permission set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked in a large global organisation where only two profiles were allowed - system admin and non system admin.

All applications that were developed had a Permission Set developed for that application and assigned only to the users that needed that application.

It meant that base permissions, like Export Reports, were easy to maintain for all users, while application specific permissions were layered on top of that via Permission Sets.

When creating a custom field you would not give visibility to any profile at all.  Instead you set it in the Permission Set for the app.

One downside was with Page Layout assignments, if you have an object with multiple layouts and you want two different apps to view different layouts for the same Record Type you can't do it.

There are always trade offs but I thought this approach worked well.